# audio recorded from the android can not be played in the browser

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I have 3 audio files with different extensions recorded from the android:

https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180325/bbf39f2e-5934-44cc-b22b-bf7b0e17b1cf.mp3

https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180127/977833ee-338e-4962-9d1e-1ff0a78e26da.3gp

https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180403/1656f7bb-9caf-4828-a083-41a8bb939c69.webm

none of them can be played back in an html5 audio tag, but if I upload them to a computer and try to play it from the player, they work normally.

```html
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180325/bbf39f2e-5934-44cc-b22b-bf7b0e17b1cf.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180127/977833ee-338e-4962-9d1e-1ff0a78e26da.3gp">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://djangoapp-konnex-crm-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/files/180403/1656f7bb-9caf-4828-a083-41a8bb939c69.webm" type="audio/webm">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

What do I need to do to play the audio recorded from the android?

Comment: It depends in what format you wrote the audio. Maybe html5 does not support audio codecs in recorded audio

Comment: Can you show code how you are recording audio?

Comment: Nugzar. how are you. Investigate recording process carefully :). Check it with another(not recorded) files as well. Good Luck.